# ASP.NET MVC Register Bundles in Application_BeginRequest(), is this possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundle, global-asax

I will need to add a bit complexity to the BundleConfig of my ASP.NET MVC Application. The fact is that, my application has internationalization features, and each view page needs to load a specific javascript file that follows the convention controllername_actionname.js.

To achieve something like this, I will need to pass a cookie 'lang' and the request controller/action name into Bundle Config and register different bundles for different controller action/views. I will need to modify BundleConfig.RegisterBundles to accept two more parameters for language and url information.

But the problem is, by default Bundles are registered in the method Application_Start(). I cannot acquire information about language setting cookie and request URL from Application_Start() as they do not exist, I can only grab this data at method Application_BeginRequest(). So I wonder, is it possible to move the Bundle registration code from Application_Start() to Application_BeginRequest().

Instead of this:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
    }
}
```

I will have the below code instead:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        var lang = (Request.Cookies["lang"] == null) ? "en" : Request.Cookies["lang"].Value;
        var url = Request.Url;
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles, lang, url);        
    }
}
```

Is this possible? If not, in what way can I pass additional server-specific parameter to Bundle.RegisterBundles()? Anyone know what to do with this?

Comment: I don't know the actual answer, but bundles are used to create a global cache of combined and possibly minified resource files (css, js). The initialization calls use `static` methods because they add to the global cache. So if problems arise, then this should explain why. And as a reference see this: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Comment: Is it possible to simply register all of your bundles? Then, in the view itself, you could do something like `@Scripts.Render(string.Format("~/{0}/some-bundle.js", ViewBag.Locale))` (or some other way of passing the cookie value to the view). So, for US English, you get `@Scripts.Render("~/en-us/some-bundle.js")`.